# 'Edit Profile' overwrites my Display Name

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, sign-up

When I do edit my profile, my display name is overwritten and the text box is populated with something like user12345 format. I have to refill the text box with my old name everytime before I hit 'Save'

Comment: We tracked this down today - expect a fix to go live tomorrow AM.

Comment: @Nick did it affect other users?

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this went out in the latest build (build rev `2017.1.11.24640`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your account has been created today. Maybe you have just created an account over and over again.

Make sure to *log on* instead of *sign up*, as the buttons are named in the top bar.

Comment: "Created an account over and over again" should not be a thing. Reasonable guess! But this sounds like a bug more so than something that needs a workaround. A couple weird things have been happening with display names in the last couple of weeks. Might be related to A/B tests we're running... but either way, I was hoping to look into it last week and then more pressing things happened, so with even more reports coming in, I'll bump it up on my list and/or at least find someone else to dig in ASAP.

Comment: Okay. I will leave the answer here or else someone will post something similar. I will delete it once you have found the reason.